# Is clang's thread sanitizer reporting a false positive?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, clang++

Consider the following, simple parallel computation of the /square/ of the elements of a vector using the `OpenMP` library. After the computation I print the vector element by element. However, I still get a data race reported by Clang's thread sanitizer `TSAN`. I'm using `clang v16.0.3` on an M1 Mac. Is this a false positive, or am I missing something?

`clang++ -fsanitize=thread -libomp -g main.cpp -lm ; LIB_OMP_THREADS=4 ./a.out`

##### `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void Square(int& x) {
    x = x * x;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i) {
        Square(numbers[i]);
    }

    for (const auto& number : numbers) {
        std::cout << number << " "; // data race reported here!?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need openmp to be built with tsan instrumentation enabled (-LIBOMP_TSAN_SUPPORT) in order for tsan to work with it, although I think they replaced that with another tool in recent LLVM/Clang versions (https://reviews.llvm.org/D45890, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/681055ea694b1de21a52b319329e5d4f9b1b807d).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, but my guess it that a thread starts printing the numbers before all thread have finished because there is no synchronization in your code. I would suggest closing the `omp parallel` before printing or ad a barrier

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel for` guarantees all the internal threads are joined as for loop goes out of scope. My investigations show that it's just that OpenMP does not play nice with Thread Sanitizer and gives false positives. The same code written with simple threading runs without TSAN reporting any issues.