# Persistent Data Race Warnings in C++ Parallel Program despite Mutex Usage

Tags: c++, openmp, mutex, race-condition, thread-sanitizer

I'm encountering persistent data race warnings in my C++ parallel program despite using mutexes. I've implemented a solution using OpenMP and mutexes to synchronize access to shared data, but I continue to receive ThreadSanitizer warnings regarding data races.

**Code Overview:**

I have a program that reads data from a file, performs parallel computations on it, and faces issues with the memory deallocation. The relevant portions of the code involve managing a shared vector using OpenMP parallelism and mutexes.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>
#include <mutex>

void readTextPointList(int n, int d, const std::string &strFileName, std::vector<std::vector<double>> &result)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> PointList;
  std::string strLine;
  std::ifstream inFile(strFileName);

  if (inFile.is_open())
  {
    int i = 0;
    while (getline(inFile, strLine) && i < n)
    {
      if (strLine.size() != 0)
      {
        std::stringstream sin(strLine);
        std::vector<double> values(d);
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
          double aa;
          sin >> aa;
          values[j] = aa;
        }
        PointList.push_back(values);
        i++;
      }
    }
    inFile.close();

    // Use std::move to transfer ownership
    result = std::move(PointList);
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Error: Unable to open file." << std::endl;
  }
}

std::mutex solveMutex;

void solve(std::vector<std::vector<double>> &data, size_t width, size_t start)
{
  std::vector<double> tuple(width);

  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(solveMutex); // Lock the critical section
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; ++i)
    {
      tuple[i] = data[start][i];
    }
  }

  // No need to unlock explicitly; std::lock_guard takes care of it when it goes out of scope
}

auto main(int argc, char **argv) -> int
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Usage: DIMENSIONALITY WINDOW" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  size_t width = strtoul(argv[1], nullptr, 10);
  size_t datasize = strtoul(argv[2], nullptr, 10);

  // Read the data into a shared vector
  std::string filename = "mydata.txt";
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> data;

  readTextPointList(datasize, width, filename, data);

  int core_number = 2;

  int step = datasize / core_number + 1;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
  for (int i = core_number - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    solve(data, width, i * step);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Compilation:**

I'm compiling the code with the following commands:

```bash
g++ -Wall -g -Wextra -fsanitize=thread -pedantic -std=c++20 -O3 -m64 -fopenmp main.cpp
```

**Issue Details:**

Despite using a mutex (`solveMutex`) to protect critical sections, I'm consistently receiving ThreadSanitizer warnings related to data races. The warnings specifically point to memory deallocation functions such as `operator delete`.

**What I've Tried:**

- I've attempted to protect critical sections with `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`.
- Checked for proper mutex usage and placement.

**Environment:**

- Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

I would appreciate any insights into why these data race warnings persist and how to resolve them effectively. Additionally, any suggestions on improving the overall design or handling memory would be valuable.

```cpp
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=25822)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7b0800000060 by main thread:
    #0 operator delete(void*, unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_new_delete.cpp:150 (libtsan.so.0+0x8e878)
    #1 __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<double>::deallocate(double*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:145 (a.out+0x484c)
    #2 std::allocator<double>::deallocate(double*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/allocator.h:199 (a.out+0x484c)
    #3 std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<double> >::deallocate(std::allocator<double>&, double*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:496 (a.out+0x484c)
    #4 std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_deallocate(double*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:354 (a.out+0x484c)
    #5 std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::~_Vector_base() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:335 (a.out+0x484c)
    #6 std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::~vector() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:683 (a.out+0x484c)
    #7 void std::destroy_at<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_construct.h:88 (a.out+0x484c)
    #8 void std::_Destroy<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_construct.h:149 (a.out+0x484c)
    #9 void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*>(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_construct.h:163 (a.out+0x484c)
    #10 void std::_Destroy<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*>(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_construct.h:196 (a.out+0x484c)
    #11 void std::_Destroy<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:848 (a.out+0x484c)
    #12 std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::~vector() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:680 (a.out+0x484c)
    #13 main /home/walid/Desktop/minimise/build sanitize/1_________decl.cpp:90 (a.out+0x2c79)

  Previous read of size 8 at 0x7b0800000060 by thread T5 (mutexes: write M11):
    #0 solve(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >&, unsigned long, unsigned long) /home/walid/Desktop/minimise/build sanitize/1_________decl.cpp:56 (a.out+0x310b)
    #1 main._omp_fn.0 /home/walid/Desktop/minimise/build sanitize/1_________decl.cpp:86 (a.out+0x329d)
    #2 <null> <null> (libgomp.so.1+0x1dc0d)

  Mutex M11 (0x55bd20bbf160) created at:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4240 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (a.out+0x30cf)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (a.out+0x30cf)
    #3 std::lock_guard<std::mutex>::lock_guard(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:229 (a.out+0x30cf)
    #4 solve(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >&, unsigned long, unsigned long) /home/walid/Desktop/minimise/build sanitize/1_________decl.cpp:53 (a.out+0x30cf)
    #5 main._omp_fn.0 /home/walid/Desktop/minimise/build sanitize/1_________decl.cpp:86 (a.out+0x329d)
    #6 <null> <null> (libgomp.so.1+0x1dc0d)

  Thread T5 (tid=25828, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605b8)
    #1 <null> <null> (libgomp.so.1+0x1e25f)
    #2 __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58 (libc.so.6+0x29d8f)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_new_delete.cpp:150 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
==================
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=25822)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7b3000000000 by main thread:
    #0 operator delete(void*, unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_new_delete.cpp:150 (libtsan.so.0+0x8e878)
    #1 __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::deallocate(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:145 (a.out+0x487a)
    #2 std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >::deallocate(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/allocator.h:199 (a.out+0x487a)
    #3 std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:496 (a.out+0x487a)
    #4 std::_Vector_base<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::_M_deallocate(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:354 (a.out+0x487a)
    #5 std::_Vector_base<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::~_Vector_base() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:335 (a.out+0x487a)
    #6 std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::~vector() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:683 (a.out+0x487a)
    #7 main /home/walid/Desktop/minimise/build sanitize/1_________decl.cpp:90 (a.out+0x2c79)

  Previous read of size 8 at 0x7b3000000000 by thread T5 (mutexes: write M11):
    #0 std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator[](unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1046 (a.out+0x30f6)
    #1 solve(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >&, unsigned long, unsigned long) /home/walid/Desktop/minimise/build sanitize/1_________decl.cpp:56 (a.out+0x30f6)
    #2 main._omp_fn.0 /home/walid/Desktop/minimise/build sanitize/1_________decl.cpp:86 (a.out+0x329d)
    #3 <null> <null> (libgomp.so.1+0x1dc0d)

  Mutex M11 (0x55bd20bbf160) created at:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:4240 (libtsan.so.0+0x53908)
    #1 __gthread_mutex_lock /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/gthr-default.h:749 (a.out+0x30cf)
    #2 std::mutex::lock() /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:100 (a.out+0x30cf)
    #3 std::lock_guard<std::mutex>::lock_guard(std::mutex&) /usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:229 (a.out+0x30cf)
    #4 solve(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >&, unsigned long, unsigned long) /home/walid/Desktop/minimise/build sanitize/1_________decl.cpp:53 (a.out+0x30cf)
    #5 main._omp_fn.0 /home/walid/Desktop/minimise/build sanitize/1_________decl.cpp:86 (a.out+0x329d)
    #6 <null> <null> (libgomp.so.1+0x1dc0d)

  Thread T5 (tid=25828, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:969 (libtsan.so.0+0x605b8)
    #1 <null> <null> (libgomp.so.1+0x1e25f)
    #2 __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58 (libc.so.6+0x29d8f)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race ../../../../src/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_new_delete.cpp:150 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
==================
ThreadSanitizer: reported 2 warnings
```

Comment: As shown, `solve` is a no-op; it has no side effects, calling it is pointless. Is it the same in your actual code?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik no I just minimised the code of solve() function, but I even got data race with those few lines of code.

Comment: OpenMP libraries don't automatically work together with ThreadSanitizer. Make sure that this is supported on your implementation and what you need to potentially customize (e.g. compile the OpenMP library with thread sanitizer instrumentation). Generally thread sanitizer only guarantees no false positives if all code including libraries is compiled with instrumentation and only uses supported synchronization primitives (and it doesn't support all C++ constructs).

Comment: Your lock is quite pointless - you copy from read only to local vector under the lock.

Comment: OpenMP and C++ use very different threads. Not knowing what thread-sanitizer does, it wouldn't surprise me if it couldn't even see the OMP threads. If you really need locks I would use OpenMP locks.

Comment: Apart the fact the lock is useless here as noted by @Slava, what's the point of a OpenMP region that is almost entirely locked?

Comment: I also agree with @VictorEijkhout: try using only OpenMP features or only C++ threads features, not mixing both if possible. Instead of the mutex here you could simply use an OpenMP `critical` directive (albeit useless in this code).

Comment: Random other comment: use better naming. Your `pointlist` is a vector of vectors. So that's 2D, rather than a list. However, I suspect that `int d` stands for the dimensionality of a point. So 1. `std::vector<double> values(d);` should not be `values` but `components` or `coordinates`. and 2. instead of a vector of size `d`, use an `std::array<double,d>`. Then your pointlist becomes a vector of size-d arrays, and it's clearer what you are doing.

Comment: GCC has no support for OpenMP-aware data race detection for ThreadSanitizer. The data race reports highlight the lack of understanding for OpenMP synchronization (barrier at the end of the parallel region). You can use Clang instead to get OpenMP-aware data race detection from libarcher. Unfortunately, Ubuntu packaging bricks libarcher. You can use the binary release from LLVM instead: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-17.0.6/clang+llvm-17.0.6-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-22.04.tar.xz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also encountered this problem recently. After my search , I found that need to build the OpenMP runtime library with TSAN [Can I use Thread Sanitizer for OpenMP programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004809/can-i-use-thread-sanitizer-for-openmp-programs?rq=2) and [Is clang's thread sanitizer reporting a false positive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76295119/is-clangs-thread-sanitizer-reporting-a-false-positive). Hope this can solve your problem. Have a good day:D